# Is it possible to create SQL query templates?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a couple of tables as data sources which have extremely similar structure. I only care about some columns of them and I want to join them. So what I do at the moment is:

```
SELECT 'table_a' AS source, col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table_a as source_table
INNER JOIN other on source_table.id = other.id

UNION ALL

SELECT 'table_b' AS source, col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table_b as source_table
INNER JOIN other on source_table.id = other.id

UNION ALL

SELECT 'table_c' AS source, col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table_c as source_table
INNER JOIN other on source_table.id = other.id

UNION ALL

SELECT 'table_d' AS source, col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table_d as source_table
INNER JOIN other on source_table.id = other.id
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
query(param1, param2) := {
    SELECT param1 AS source, col1, col2, col3, col4
    FROM param2 as source_table
    INNER JOIN other on source_table.id = other.id
}

query('table_a', table_a)
UNION ALL
query('table_b', table_b)
UNION ALL
query('table_c', table_c)
UNION ALL
query('table_d', table_d)
```

I know how to do this within the programming language (using a templating engine and constructing the query string).

Is something like this possible within SQL (Snowflake Warehouse)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly that I'm afraid. However, you can use Snowflake [Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html) (SP) to effectively achieve this. You can construct the SQL query text in SP based on the parameters passed to it, and then executing it. You can e.g. pass to it an array of table names etc.

One problem is that today SPs in Snowflake [do not return the result of the query directly](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html#values-returned-by-stored-procedures-are-not-directly-usable-in-sql). To overcome this, you can e.g. save the result of the query in a new table (with the name hardcoded in SP, or passed as a parameter to SP) and then query it with a separate SELECT.